# Create New Directory and Inserting Data in Firebase

Tags: jquery, firebase

i want to create five new directories in Firebase dynamically. Also i want to insert data in those directories dynamically. I wrote this jquery script for that purpose.

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
 var dataRef = new Firebase('https://blr-reaction-buttons.firebaseio.com/' + i);
 dataRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {
  var tempdata = snapshot.val();
  if (!tempdata) {
   tempdata=50;
   dataRef.set(tempdata);
  }
 });
}
```

but instead of creating multiple directories, it just create one directory (in fact the last one) (pic below)...

[image: generated directory of my firebase script]

I just don't understand why this is happening. Pls help. Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it because Firebase framework creates only one instance of Firebase and it simply only changes it 5 times?

Comment: Not really, in this case it is simply the fact that the `on('value',` all trigger asynchronously. By the time the code inside those functions runs, the value of `i` is `4`. So you end up setting the value of child `4` 5 times.

Answer (score 6):

Firebase doesn't really have directories, but instead everything is a JavaScript object. This means that the closest thing to a directory is a key that contains another object :)

In other words, I'm assuming you want to see something like this in Forge:
[image: firebase forge]

To make your Firebase look like that, you can create a JavaScript object locally and save it to the root node using `set`. You can then use the read callback `value` to listen for changes. Here's the code that implements this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.15/firebase.js'></script>
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js'>
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
  /* Write 5 numbered objects, each set to 50 */

  // Create a new Firebase data reference to the root
  var dataRef = 
      new Firebase('https://test-firebase-please-ignore.firebaseio.com/');
  // Create a JavaScript object to hold stuff
  var tempData = {};
  // Add 5 things to it
  for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    tempData[i] = {value: 50};
  }
  // Save it to Firebase
  dataRef.set(tempData);


  /* Meanwhile, create a listener that gets updates when the data changes */

  dataRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    // Log the whole thing
    console.log(snapshot.val());
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic case of asynchronicity working against your instincts.

When you call `dataRef.on('value',` it may reach out to the server to get that value for you. That operation may take a long time, so instead of waiting for the result (which would block the browser) the optation instead calls you back when the value is available.

Unfortunately by the time the callback function gets invoked, you've changed the `dataRef` value to point to something else: the last dataRef `4`.

It's like your code executes in this order:

```
var i = 0
var dataRef = new Firebase('https://blr-reaction-buttons.firebaseio.com/' + i);
dataRef.on('value', ... };

// Your callback is not invoked immediately, but only once the server returns the value.
// But in the meantime your main code continues with the next iteration through the loop

i = 1;
var dataRef = new Firebase('https://blr-reaction-buttons.firebaseio.com/' + i);
dataRef.on('value', ... };

// Same as before: we're now waiting for 2 values to become available

i = 2;
var dataRef = new Firebase('https://blr-reaction-buttons.firebaseio.com/' + i);
dataRef.on('value', ... };

// Let's say that all values becomes available at this point, so your callback code executes

function (snapshot) {
  var tempdata = snapshot.val();
  if (!tempdata) {
   tempdata=50;
   dataRef.set(tempdata);
  }
 });
function (snapshot) {
  var tempdata = snapshot.val();
  if (!tempdata) {
   tempdata=50;
   dataRef.set(tempdata);
  }
 });
function (snapshot) {
  var tempdata = snapshot.val();
  if (!tempdata) {
   tempdata=50;
   dataRef.set(tempdata);
  }
 });
```

Note that line `dataRef.set` in all three cases? At this point the single variable `dataRef` refers to the object at ref `2`. You end up setting a value to the same ref three times.

A simple solution is to simply always set the value:

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
 var dataRef = new Firebase('https://blr-reaction-buttons.firebaseio.com/' + i);
 var tempdata=50;
 dataRef.set(tempdata);
}
```

Jenny Murphy's approach will also work fine btw. As will capturing the different `dataRef` values in a so-called closure (google for **javascript closure** or **immediately invoked function expression** to learn more).